# camer2basic surface size error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

i am working on camera2basic sample of google
this project : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic
but when open camera i get two errors :

1. > Surface with size (w=720, h=960) and format 0x1 is not valid, size not
   > in valid set: [1440x1080, 1280x720, 1056x864, 960x720, 880x720,
   > 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 528x432, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
2. > [unnamed-1362-40] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned

i see a lot of answers but not solved my problem .
please help me .
i test this app on samsung a5 then get that error

samsung a5:

1. Resolution:720 x 1280 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~294 ppi density)
2. size:5.0 inches, 68.9 cm2 (~71.0% screen-to-body ratio)

*/////////Edited*
new error on lg g3

> Surface with size (w=1440, h=1920) and format 0x1 is not valid, size
> not in valid set: [1920x1440, 1920x1080, 1776x1080, 1440x1080,
> 1280x960, 1280x720, 960x720, 880x720, 864x480, 848x480, 800x480,
> 720x480, 768x432, 640x480, 576x432, 480x320, 384x288, 352x288,
> 320x240, 240x160, 176x144, 160x120]

## The main question is why surface create with wrong size ?

Answer (score 0):

change your surface size by 720 x 1280

Comment: what about other devices with different sizes.

Comment: Are you getting the size array if yes then pick the largest one

Comment: yes i do. in camera2basic sample they getting the largest size

Comment: @A.Hamzavi  so what's the problem

Comment: Post the screenshots of it